# Confusion on ARMv8 PMU events of l3d_cache_refill and ll_cache_miss_rd in Cortex-A78

Tags: linux, arm, perf, armv8

I am testing process's memory bandwidth in Cortex-A78 Linux with perf.  And I got following output.

```
       18,312,265      ll_cache_miss_rd          #   0.507 M/sec                    (28.64%)
       36,006,163      l3_cache_refill           #   0.996 M/sec                    (42.68%)
```

From Cortex-A78's PMU document, it says,

> LL_CACHE_MISS_RD         Last level cache miss, read.
> • If  CPUECTLR.EXTLLC is set: This event counts any cacheable read
> transaction which returns a data source of 'DRAM', 'remote' or
> 'inter-cluster peer'.
> • If CPUECTLR.EXTLLC is not set: This event is a
> duplicate of the L*D_CACHE_REFILL_RD event corresponding to the last
> level of cache implemented – L3D_CACHE_REFILL_RD if both per-core L2
> and cluster L3 are implemented, L2D_CACHE_REFILL_RD if only one is
> implemented, or L1D_CACHE_REFILL_RD if neither is implemented.

In my Cortex-A78 system, L3 is the last level, and the CPUECTLR.EXTLLC is 0, so `ll_cache_miss_rd is a duplicate of L3D_CACHE_REFILL_RD`.  But it is NOT, the refill event has double number of miss_rd event!

Since the event ID of L3D_CACHE_REFILL is 0x2A, I added `-e r2a` to my perf command to capture the raw event counts, the line of r2A eventhas the similar number of `ll_cache_miss_rd`, which is much different with the line of `l3_cache_refill`.
Did I miss anything on inteprating the events based from the document or something wrong in my testing with perf in ARMv8?